# Exporting obj with f v/vt/vn instead of v//vn

Tags: uv, export, faces, file-format

I need to export a model to .obj-format for a school project. The faces must be defined like this 
`f v/vt/vn` 
but they are defined like this 
`f v//vn` 
even though I checked both "include UVs" and "write normals".

What could be wrong? 
Thanks, Anickyan

Comment: It'll help to have a bit more information. When you say "faces must be defined like this", you don't say who declared that they must be. Same for "they are defined like this" -- you don't say who or what defined them like that. Having an example blend file that shows your problem also helps.

Comment: Well, the program that uses the obj files can only handle obj-files where the faces are defined `f v/vt/vn`.

Blender defines them `f v//vn` when I export obj-files, no matter what options I try.

Comment: vt is the texture coordinates, have you unwrapped the object so that you have uv coordinates to export?